# Score Card Research - Have I been hacked?

Tags: javascript, web

I was debugging a javascript game that I made, so I went to the console on chrome. I know about the first error, but what is the scorecardresearch.com get request that failed? Have I been hacked? Please help. Thanks!

Here is the console output:

> GET http://aquariumkids.com/css/bg.png 404 (Not Found) (index):342
>
> GET http://b.scorecardresearch.com/b?c1=7&c2=10137436&c3=1&ns__t=1405734869806&…3Ddefault%232&c9=http%3A%2F%2Faquariumkids.com%2Fmake-your-own-aquarium%2F net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED beacon.js:1

Comment: I don't think this is really a programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[They seem to be a market research company that track your information.](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2012/apr/23/scorecardresearch-tracking-trackers-cookies-web-monitoring)

> It provides market research data to website owners through a mixture
> of online surveys and the use of web beacons.
>
> ScorecardResearch's privacy policy says its tracking will collect
> information such as:
>
> - when your browser visited a website
> - what page of the website it was
> - the title of the web page
> - IP address

Comment: It appears that Stack Overflow itself uses ScorecardResearch.

Comment: That's a +1 from me for being called McLovin